# How does Windows 8 Loop Back work?

Tags: windows-8, loopback

Local services are not available to Windows 8 apps. If I enable Loop Back, then I can access local services, but my Windows 8 app will not be allowed in the Store. If I do not care about the Store (for a line of business app) how do I use Loop Back?

Answer (score 2):

[This document tells you how](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh780593.aspx); however, it also includes the following note:

> Warning  Loopback is only permitted for development purposes. Usage by
>   apps installed outside of Visual Studio is not permitted.

I read that as even sideloaded apps are not permitted to do so; though, I'm not sure how that could be enforced.

Comment: The language is not clear, I admit. That is not what it means. If you are writing an internal app, then there is no problem using Loop Back. That's the official word, by the way.