# Metro - does loopback-exemption work for sideloaded apps in Windows 8.1 Professional?

Tags: microsoft-metro, windows-8.1

Can anyone confirm or deny that Loopback Exemption is working for their sideloaded apps under Windows 8.1 Professional, without installing visual studio on the sideloaded machine? Has anyone successfully deployed to machines without developer accounts or developer tools using this technique?

**Background information**

We've developed a metro app that will be sideloaded. The metro app needs to interface with local web services via localhost. It appears that Loopback Isolation Exemptions are not affecting the sideloaded machine's ability to connect to localhost, even though they work fine on my Dev box.

According to Jerry Nixon, who is credible (MSFT), Loopback Isolation did work with non-debug, non-visual studio apps in Windows 8.0, even though the verbiage in the original MSDN article kind of implies they don't or aren't supposed to: [How does Windows 8 Loop Back work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13770863/how-does-windows-8-loop-back-work).

I've enabled loopback isolation per [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh780593.aspx), and ensured that the apppackage is found. When that didn't work, I've also tried making all apps loopback exempt using  [this tool](http://loopback.codeplex.com/), also to no avail. Is this working for anyone? Trying to decide whether to keep pressing further, and if anyone can confirm that it's at least working for some deployment, then I'll keep pressing to find out why it's not working. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Loopback exemption works fine. It allows sideloaded apps in Windows 8.1 Professional to access web services on localhost, in Release or Debug Mode. This is somewhat contrary to the confusing verbiage of the original MSDN article.

We had a completely separate problem with the way IIS was configured.

Also, here's an additional word of warning for anyone going through this process, as it may be your next problem: if you want to sideload an app in Windows 8.1 Pro, you will have to renew a developer license every month, spend $3000 on a 100-pack of sideloading keys plus additional monthly fees, or upgrade Windows to Enterprise Edition. There is no legal alternative that I am aware of.